# Why can't I get the center? in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, plugins

I use [scrollama.js](https://github.com/russellgoldenberg/scrollama/blob/master/build/scrollama.js).
scrollama is a plugin that allows to center reference lines using Intersection Observer.

---

### What I want to do

[image: like this]

Now (default), I get the center based on `body`,
I want to get the center based on the specific element `#cont` (= content).

And I changed the code of scrollama.js like this.

---

### Current status

Line 213

```
function handleResize() {
    // viewH = window.innerHeight;
    // pageH = getPageHeight();
    viewH = document.getElementById("cont").offsetHeight;  // change
    pageH = document.getElementById("cont").offsetHeight;  // change

    offsetMargin = offsetVal * viewH;

    if (isReady) {
      stepOffsetHeight = stepEl.map(function (el) { return el.offsetHeight; });
      stepOffsetTop = stepEl.map(getOffsetTop);
      if (isEnabled) { updateIO(); }
    }

    if (isDebug) { update({ id: id, stepOffsetHeight: stepOffsetHeight, offsetMargin: offsetMargin, offsetVal: offsetVal }); }
  }
```

result:
[image: current]

For now, I could get `#cont`, but the reference line is at the top.. (This dotted line is a debugging tool for scrollama)

I thought this would take the center if I changed the element scrollama.js gets and changed it like this, but is there anything else I have to change?

---

### Code likely to be relevant to get the center

I extracted all the places where `viewH` and `pageH` are used in scrollama.

```
function scrollama() {

//【Line 143~】
var viewH = 0;
var pageH = 0;

//【Line 213~】
  function handleResize() {
    viewH = window.innerHeight;
    pageH = getPageHeight();

    offsetMargin = offsetVal * viewH;
  }

//【Line 471~】
// jump into viewport
  function updateViewportAboveIO() {
    io.viewportAbove = stepEl.map(function (el, i) {
      var marginTop = pageH - stepOffsetTop[i];    // <- here
      var marginBottom = offsetMargin - viewH - stepOffsetHeight[i];    // <- here
      var rootMargin = marginTop + "px 0px " + marginBottom + "px 0px";
      var options = { rootMargin: rootMargin };
      // console.log(options);
      var obs = new IntersectionObserver(intersectViewportAbove, options);
      obs.observe(el);
      return obs;
    });
  }

  function updateViewportBelowIO() {
    io.viewportBelow = stepEl.map(function (el, i) {
      var marginTop = -offsetMargin - stepOffsetHeight[i];
      var marginBottom = offsetMargin - viewH + stepOffsetHeight[i] + pageH; // <- here
      var rootMargin = marginTop + "px 0px " + marginBottom + "px 0px";
      var options = { rootMargin: rootMargin };
      // console.log(options);
      var obs = new IntersectionObserver(intersectViewportBelow, options);
      obs.observe(el);
      return obs;
    });
  }

  // look above for intersection
  function updateStepAboveIO() {
    io.stepAbove = stepEl.map(function (el, i) {
      var marginTop = -offsetMargin + stepOffsetHeight[i];
      var marginBottom = offsetMargin - viewH;    // <- here
      var rootMargin = marginTop + "px 0px " + marginBottom + "px 0px";
      var options = { rootMargin: rootMargin };
      // console.log(options);
      var obs = new IntersectionObserver(intersectStepAbove, options);
      obs.observe(el);
      return obs;
    });
  }

  // look below for intersection
  function updateStepBelowIO() {
    io.stepAbove = stepEl.map(function (el, i) {
      var marginTop = -offsetMargin;
      var marginBottom = offsetMargin - viewH + stepOffsetHeight[i];    // <- here
      var rootMargin = marginTop + "px 0px " + marginBottom + "px 0px";
      var options = { rootMargin: rootMargin };
      // console.log(options);
      var obs = new IntersectionObserver(intersectStepBelow, options);
      obs.observe(el);
      return obs;
    });
  }

  // progress progress tracker
  function updateStepProgressIO() {
    io.stepProgress = stepEl.map(function (el, i) {
      var marginTop = stepOffsetHeight[i] - offsetMargin;
      var marginBottom = -viewH + offsetMargin;    // <- here
      var rootMargin = marginTop + "px 0px " + marginBottom + "px 0px";
      var threshold = createThreshold(stepOffsetHeight[i]);
      var options = { rootMargin: rootMargin, threshold: threshold };
      // console.log(options);
      var obs = new IntersectionObserver(intersectStepProgress, options);
      obs.observe(el);
      return obs;
    });
  }

}
```